# Is there any scenario where still background service is preferred?

Tags: android, android-service

After reading about WorkManager, Job scheduler, Firebase dispatcher and services, I am thinking if there is any scenario where we still use background service?

App specs: min SDK is 19 and targetting API 28.

Note: Asking only about background service, not foreground services.

Comment: A Service can not run in background (without a visible process) .. So preference does not matter if its not there anymore ..

Comment: @ADM To be clear, you imply that we need not bother about background service anymore. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would say that there's no more use case for the background service. For work that cannot be deferred, we need to start a foreground service. For work that can be deferred, we use WorkManager to ensure that the task is performed sometime in the future.